# Can't create a System protocol

Tags: clojure, protocols

I'm writing a [Entity Component System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system). Part of my plan is to have a protocol called `System` that a system must fulfill to use the ECS.

The problem is, Clojure complains if I try to create a protocol called `System`; seemingly because it clashes with `java.lang.System`.

```
(ns entity.system)

(defprotocol System
  ; Protocol methods)
```

yields

> CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Expecting var, but System is mapped to class java.lang.System, compiling:(C:\Users\slomi\IdeaProjects\entity\src\entity\system.clj:3:1)

I tried excluding `System` by adding both `(:refer-clojure :exclude [System])` and `(:refer-clojure :exclude [java.lang.System])`, but neither did anything; I received the same error again.

Of course I could just name it something else, but `System` seems the most appropriate name, and something like `entity.entity-system/Entity-System` or even `entity.system/Entity-System` seems overly redundant.

How can I exclude `java.lang.System` from the namespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is `ns-unmap`

```
(ns-unmap *ns* 'System)

(defprotocol System
  (add [this that]))

(extend-protocol System
  Long
  (add [this that]
    (format "%d + %d is %d" this that (+ this that))))

(add 2 3)
;;=> "2 + 3 is 5"
```

Comment: Lovely. Thank you.